# How can I automatically connect my phone to the stronger Wifi signal around it?

Tags: wi-fi, network-signal

I have a Google Nexus 4 and have two wi-fi networks that I use in my home. Since they are in some range of one another my phone stays connected to the router that's farther away from the one I'm closer to. Is there a way or app that can connect me to the stronger wifi signal around me when I move around my house?

Comment: Are those wifi networks sharing the same channel?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no native method for this (at least to my knowledge). But [WiFi Switcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sarvaria.wifiswitcher) does exactly that. According to its description:

> The tool checks the registered WIFI networks every 20 seconds. If one of these networks has better signal strength than the currently one, the tool changes the WIFI network to this better one.

But it's not that well rated (3.2 with 75 ratings). The alternative [WiFi Jumper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goramart.wifijumper) has a better rating (4.1@194), but is not free:

> - Automatically connect to the strongest available WIFI (scaninterval configurable)
> - Even unknown, but unsecured networks can be used automatically (configurable)
> - Optional: create Wifi Zones based on one or more Radio Cells to automatically start and stop Wifi Hardware.

Comment: This also might be a battery drain due to the inherent inreliability/fluctuations of/in Wi-Fi strength measurements. It can differ based on a lot of factors, so doing this at all might be a bad idea to begin with, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 +1 yes, continual scanning can suck the battery juice, wait and see if Android 4.3 resolves this, as apparently it's supposed to be able to scan without activating wifi...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manualy by using Wifi Analyzer and then connecting to the strongest wifi around you. I don't know an app that could automate this for you.
[Link to app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&feature=search_result)

Comment: You might want to correct the first sentence of your answer -- see mine :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another third-party method using "[WiFi Connect](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=wifi%20connect%20tasker)" as a [plugin](http://tasker.wikidot.com/plug-ins-and-3rd-party) for [Tasker](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/releases/). There is a tutorial on YouTube, [described](https://www.hollywoodfrodo.com/tasker-video-tutorials-lesson-list.html) as follows:

**Switch to Strongest WiFi Signal on Android**

> Based on a request from a viewer, in this lesson we create a profile
>   and task to test the strength of the current WiFi signal and switch to
>   another one if it's weak.  Best utilized in a house or business where
>   there are multiple hotspots/connections, we cover several new topics
>   including Splitting Variables, Testing Text to see if it contains a
>   word or character string, Flashing variable info, and Reading/Writing
>   files.  (This lesson also makes use of a Tasker plug-in called WiFi
>   Connect.)